# Fatwire 7.6.1 RevisionTrackingManager get method fails

Tags: fatwire

//CSElement code
//Am trying to get revision numbers of asset and assetdata using the RevisionTrackingManager interface but its throwing an exception

```
String assetId = "1293727029653";
String assetType = "NSP_Content_C";
String selectedRevision = "2";

AssetId aId = new AssetIdImpl(assetType, Long.valueOf(assetId));
RevisionTrackingManager rtm = new RevisionTrackingManagerImpl(ics);
AssetData revisedAsset = null;
try
{   
    out.println("<br/>-------------Calling RevisionTrackingManager-------------");
    out.println("<br/>Total versions = "+ rtm.getVersions(aId).size());
    revisedAsset = rtm.get(aId,Integer.valueOf(selectedRevision));
    out.println("After");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    out.println("<br/>Could not retrieve asset. Possibly cause: item might be checked out............" + ex.getMessage());
}


Above code throws exception and gives the message in catch block. Could anyone help me to fix this code?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what type of exception is being thrown as you are catching it all. Alternatively, you could also find an asset's version in the AssetType_T table. Hope that helps.